# There are different mantras for worshipping Lord Vishnu for different yugas. What are the meanings of them?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, mantras, translation-request, yuga

### There are different mantras to chant Lord Vishnu's name in different Yugas.

This names are known as *tārakabrahma* names.

---

- The mantra for Satya Yuga is-

  > *nārāya়ṇa parābedā nārāya়ṇa parākṣarāḥ*।
  >
  > *nārāya়ṇa paramukti nārāya়ṇa paragati:*।।

---

- The mantra for Treta Yuga is-

  > *rāma nārāya়ṇānanta mukunda madhusūdana*।
  >
  > *kṛṣṇa keśaba kaṃsāre hare baikuṇṭha bāmana*।।

---

- The mantra for Dwapara Yuga is-

  > *hare murāre madhukaiṭabhāre gopāla gobinda mukunda saure*।
  >
  > *yajñeśa nārāya়ṇa kṛṣṇa biṣṇo nirāśraya়ṃ māṃ jagadīśa rakṣa*।।

---

- The mantra for Kali Yuga is-

  > *hare kṛṣṇa hare kṛṣṇa kṛṣṇa kṛṣṇa hare hare*।
  >
  > *hare rāma hare rāma rāma rāma hare hare*।।

---

**I sincerely wish to know the meanings of the second and the third ślokas word by word and their complete meaning and significance.** Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

PS- If you translate all the ślokas here, that would be additionally helpful.

Comment: I humbly expect to know the **English meaning of all the all the words and phrases contained here along with the English translation of the said verses**. Please _do not_ write an answer stating the significance of the verses and/or which emotions these verses highlight. I already have access to that information. Thanks.

Comment: what's the source of these mantras? and few mantras are not clearly readable...

Comment: @YDS You can find these very easily in online sources and many books. I found them on a particular book called "Sri Krishna Samhita".

Comment: [This site](https://www.bhaktinomoney.space/tarakabrahma-nama-the-evolution-of-dharma/) mentions all these mantras with their meanings and other details.

Answer (score 1):

(excerpt from http://gloriouskrishna.blogspot.com/2011/11/taraka-brahma-nama-holy-name-which.html)

Taraka Brahma Nama (The Holy Name which Delivers All)
‘taraka-brahma-nama’ which means this transcendental mantra is the deliverer of one and all.

```
narayana para veda
narayana paraksara
narayana para muktir
narayana-para gatih
```

The purport behind it is -- Narayana is the abode of all vijnana, mukti (liberation), and the ultimate goal. This is aisvarya-gatah-nama; it is aisvarya, not madhurya, it is all opulence. Narayana is aisvarya-gatah-nama-narayana. Krsna-nama is madhurya, which is only available in the Kali-yuga.

```
rama narayanananta
mukunda madhusudana
krsna kesava kamsare
hare vaikuntha vamana
```

What is the purport in it? The taraka-brahma-nama in the Satya-yuga only gives santa and dasya-bhava. No other bhava, mellow, only santa and dasya. But in the Treta-yuga, the taraka-brahma-nama gives dasya (servitorship) and some glimpse of friendship, sakhya-bhava -- sakhya-nama. This Treta-yuga taraka-brahma-nama is also aisvarya gatah, all the names of Narayana are there and here it is said, multifarious -- vikrama, Lord Vamana -- trivikrama. Lord Vamana exhibited three types of vikrama, He manifested three wonderful potencies, known as trivikrama -- Vamana.

```
hare murare madhu-kaitabhare
gopala govinda mukunda saure
yajnesa narayana krsna visnos
nirasrayam mam jagadisa raksa
```

Here you will find santa, dasya, sakhya and vatsalya -- these four mellows, and nirasrayam mam jagadisa raksa. Taking complete shelter at the lotus feet of Jagadisa, the Supreme Lord of the Universe, and no other shelter.

```
hare krsna hare krsna
krsna krsna hare hare
hare rama hare rama
rama rama hare hare
```

This is madhurya, it is the best of all, it has such great potential and it is so powerful. It is madhurya, there is no aisvarya at all. In all the names in the other yugas you will find there is aisvarya, but here in the Kali-yuga -- hari-nama: Hare Krsna Hare Krsna Krsna Krsna Hare Hare, Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare; this is completely madhurya-nama, all the mellows are there. Thus Mahaprabhu chanted this: Hare Krsna Hare Krsna Krsna Krsna Hare Hare, Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare. In the names of all other yugas you will find this vikrama and mukti, but here in the taraka-brahma-nama for the Kali-yuga you will only find prema, only prema. That is said: bhakti-pade-mukti-dasi -- mukti is the maidservant standing at the doorstep of prema-bhakti. Those who are really intelligent persons, those who only de sire to accept the essence, chant this mantra: Hare Krsna Hare Krsna Krsna Krsna Hare Hare, Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare. One can chant in any place, at any time and there is no restriction at all.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But I already knew these. These information can be easily accessible through a Google search. I was not looking for these. I wanted **literal translation** of these verses along with **English meanings of all the words and phrases contained in the verses**. If you are aware of the **meanings of the all of the words and phrases**, please add the same and able to **translate these verses into English**, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

चतुर्युगेषु श्री राम नाम महात्म्यं उज्जवलं।

सर्वोत्कृष्टं न संदेहो कलौ तत्रापि सर्वदा।।

Shri Ram is evident in all 4 yugas but in Kali yug, shri Ram naam is the only way to salvation

Comment: You really provide good answers related to Shri Rama. Please try to write the source from where you quote your answer like verse no. scripture name , etc. or provide the link so that curious and interested people can read it. :)

Comment: It's quoted from "Sharda ramayan" of maa sarswati.

Comment: Okayyy..... .:)